# How to load large json(multiple object) into pandas dataframes in chuncks to avoid high memory usage?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a very large json file that is in the form of multiple objects, for small dataset, this works

```
data=pd.read_json(file,lines=True)
```

but on the same but larger dataset it would crash on 8gb ram computer, so i tried to convert it to list first with below code

```
data[]
with open(file) as file:
    for i in file:
        d = json.loads(i)
        data.append(d)'
```

then convert the list into dataframe with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

this does convert it into a list fine even with the large dataset file, but it crashes when i try to convert it into a dataframe due to it using to much memory i presume

i have tried doing

```
data[]
with open(file) as file:
    for i in file:
        d = json.loads(i)
        df=pd.DataFrame([d])'
```

I thought it would append it one by one but i think it still create one large copy in memory at once insteads, so it still crashes

how would i convert the large json file into dataframe by chuncks so it limit the memory useage?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solution, depending on your specific case. Given we don't have a data example or information on the data structure, I could offer the following:

- If the data in the json file is numeric, consider breaking it into chunks, reading each one and converting to the smallest type (float32/int), as pandas will use float64 which is more memory intensive
- use Dask for bigger-than-memory datasets, like you have.

Comment: Its large but not that large, the file size is 1.6gb. its multiple entries of seperate json. its a mix of number of string. i may be wrong but i think it only crashes because it loads a copy into memory while also has a copy while creating the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the intermediate data structures you can use a generator.

```py
def load_jsonl(filename):
    with open(filename) as fd:
        for line in fd:
            yield json.loads(line)

df = pd.DataFrame(load_jsonl(filename))
```

Comment: yeah, but i think the core issue is when create a dataframe, pandas use large amount of memory to hold a copy in memory in addition the file. hence it crash.

i tried your code, it still crash. i was wondering if there is a way to load the dataset into dataframe in chunks like you can with delimited json